# How to import all namespaces in PowerShell script

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

LogInjecter class is referencing some namespaces of nuget packages , how can I import those namespaces.

```
Write-Host “Analyzing your Solution and Inserting Log Calls”
$lib = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("D:\Telemetry.LogInjecter.dll")
$obj = new-object Telemetry.LogInjecter.LogInjecter
$result = $obj.InjectLogs()


   Write-Host “Analyzing your Solution and Inserting Log Calls”        
  //added this line
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis")
    $lib = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("D:\Telemetry.LogInjecter.dll")
    $obj = new-object Telemetry.LogInjecter.LogInjecter
    $result = $obj.InjectLogs()
```

getting this error
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The 
system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Namespace.Goes.Here")`

Comment: added this but still getting error, but still getting error,